# an error in Matlab: Input argument undefined, although variable is existing

Tags: matlab, variables

I have written this function, and I have already defined values for rg and Lp, but still when I run this function it returns the error : (Input argument "Lr" is undefined.

Error in ==> Bis at 12
    if f(Lr,rg,Xo)*f(Lr,rg,Xf)>0)

here is the function :

```
function[Lp,Xo,Xf]=Bis(Lr,rg)

Xo=0;
Xf=10;
Err=0.01;

syms x;
f=inline('(sqrt((2/3)*(((x*Lr)/3)-(x*x)+((2*x*x*x)/Lr)-((2*x*x*x*x)/(Lr*Lr))+(((2*x*x*x*x)/(Lr*Lr))*exp(-Lr/x))))-rg)');


    if f(Lr,rg,Xo)*f(Lr,rg,Xf)>0
        disp('The values you entered are not apropriate !')
        PlotLpFunction;
    Lp='unknown';
    elseif f(Lr,rg,Xo)*f(Lr,rg,Xf)==0
        if f(Lr,rg,Xo)==0
            Lp=Xo;
        elseif f(Lr,rg,Xf)==0
            Lp=Xf;
        end

    elseif f(Lr,rg,Xo)*f(Lr,rg,Xf)<0
        xi=(Xf-Xo)/2;
        while abs(f(Lr,rg,xi))>Err 
            if f(Lr,rg,xi)*f(Lr,rg,Xf)<0
                Xo=xi;
                xi=(Xo+Xf)/2;
            elseif f(Lr,rg,xi)*f(Lr,rg,Xf)>0
                Xf=xi;
                xi=(Xo+Xf)/2;   
            end
        end
        Lp=xi;
    end
```

Comment: Can you show us how you call this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code executes for me on the newest version of Matlab, other than the fact that I don't have the PlotLpFunction.

My initial impression was that you forgot to send the Lr (and all other argument) into you're inlined f function, very easy to fix by adding them as arguments to the inline function.  You'll find the full usage in [the official documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/inline.html).

The relevant part being

> `inline(expr,arg1,arg2,...)` constructs an inline function whose input
>   arguments are specified by the strings arg1, arg2,.... Multicharacter
>   symbol names may be used.

but it seems to form the inline just fine by itself on both Matlab 2011b and 2008b, from context presumably.  Answer is accepted now, so presumably that was the problem.  Can anyone else reproduce his problem?  If so please provide your Matlab version or other circumstances.

Comment: I read that .. and what I have done is that I just inserted Lr,rg in the end of my inline sentance
like this
f=inline('(sqrt((2/3)*(((x*Lr)/3)-(x*x)+((2*x*x*x)/Lr)-((2*x*x*x*x)/(Lr*Lr))+(((2*x*x*x*x)/(Lr*Lr))*exp(-Lr/x))))-rg)',Lr,rg);

Comment: I got the error : 

Input argument "Lr" is undefined.

Error in ==> Bis at 9
f=inline('(sqrt((2/3)*(((x*Lr)/3)-(x*x)+((2*x*x*x)/Lr)-((2*x*x*x*x)/(Lr*Lr))+(((2*x*x*x*x)/(Lr*Lr))*exp(-Lr/x))))-rg)',Lr,rg); 
>>

Comment: It wants the variable names as strings, so pass in 'Lr', 'rg', and 'x'

Comment: I don't think that's the problem here.                             >> f=inline('(sqrt((2/3)*(((x*Lr)/3)-(x*x)+((2*x*x*x)/Lr)-((2*x*x*x*x)/(Lr*Lr))+(((‌​2*x*x*x*x)/(Lr*Lr))*exp(-Lr/x))))-rg)')     

 

f =

 

     Inline function:

     f(Lr,rg,x) = (sqrt((2/3)*(((x*Lr)/3)-(x*x)+((2*x*x*x)/Lr)-((2*x*x*x*x)/(Lr*Lr))+(((2*x*x*x*x)/(Lr*Lr))*exp(-Lr/x))))-rg)

Comment: Ok .. when you pass these 3 variables at the same time you get this error :


Input argument "Lr" is undefined.

Error in ==> Bis at 11
    if f(Lr,rg,Xo)*f(Lr,rg,Xf)>0

Comment: >> argnames(f)

 

ans = 

 

    'Lr'

    'rg'

    'x' -- No need to explicitly name the arguments.

Comment: the funny thing is that the same command is working when you just define the variables and type it on the command window, but once it is inside the function it starts getting sloppy !

Comment: See the updated answer.  Put a break in at the `if f(Lr,rg,Xo)*f(Lr,rg,Xf)>0` line and try to execute the calls manually.

Comment: Alright my original answer was definitely wrong.  Still can't reproduce your error but your code also doesn't make any sense: you've defined `Xo` as 0 which makes the first part of your expression sym computed expression evaluate to NaN.